# Meaning of this in Java (currently in Kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin

I am looking at a class which goes like this:

```
class temp(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
    LinearLayout(context, attrs), tempInterface {
    ..................................
}
```

I just wanted to ask, how can I translate this to Java? I have been able to do this as of now:

```
public class temp extends LinearLayout implements tempInterface
    ....................
    public temp(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    ....................
}
```

In the Kotlin version, I see that `LinearLayout` is also accepting two attributes (`context` and `attrs`) whereas in Java version I see I have only defined the constructor for the primary class, i.e. `temp`. Is that okay?

Comment: `super(context, attrs)` calls the parent class' constructor

Comment: The code is fine. `super(context, attrs)` calls the constructor of LinearLayout.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a usecase where java -> kotlin in android would make any sense - i can't find one. What are you _really_ trying to achieve, John?

Answer (score -2):

What you wrote is exactly equivalent to the Kotlin code. There are several ways to valide this.

### Use Kotlin decompiler

You can copy the Kotlin code into a project that has Kotlin set up (you can find working samples), then open it in IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio.

There's a menu item: [*Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin bytecode*](https://medium.com/@mydogtom/tip-how-to-show-java-equivalent-for-kotlin-code-f7c81d76fa8), and then there's a *Decompile* button on it.
Executing this flow gives the following output:

```java
public final class temp extends LinearLayout implements tempInterface {
   public temp(@NotNull Context context, @NotNull AttributeSet attrs) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(context, "context");
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(attrs, "attrs");
      super(context, attrs);
   }
}
```

This is the exact code that Kotlin compiles to.

### Ask ChatGPT to translate it

This is perfect for [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/chat)'s capabilities, rather than asking here on SO. I tried it myself with prompt: "here's some Kotlin code, translate to Java: `<code>`" and it gave an almost perfect translation of the Kotlin code back to Java. It just missed `public` on `class`.

### Look at documentation

This being said, you probably want to create a custom view/layout in Android using the Java language. You can see the example code and other documentation here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/create-view#subclassview
If you swap between Java and Kotlin just above the code block you can find a very similar example to yours.

### Generate code from template in Android Studio

Note that usually you need 3 constructors, this is shown by looking at the code generated in Android Studio:

```java
public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, 0);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can use Android Studio's *File > New > UiComponent > Custom View*. Note that this action is context sensitive, make sure you're inside a Java or Kotlin file in an Android module, or right clicks `src/main/java` or `src/main/kotlin` to be sure.